# value count in pyspark is taking too much time

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark is very efficient in reading through a set of billion dataset within 4 seconds but the count of distinct value in a df is pretty slow and less efficient & it's taking more than 5 mins even for a small set of data, I have tried these approaches:

```
value1 = df.where(df['values'] == '1').count()
```

or

```
df.groupBy("values").count().orderBy("value_count").show()
```

both returns the correct result but the time is the essence here.
I know that ***count*** is an lazy operator but is there an alternate approach to solve this problem ?

TIA

Comment: this should be faster: `df.where("values = 1").count()`

Answer (score 0):

`Count()` is a function that makes Spark literally count through the rows. Operations like `count()`, `distinct()`, etc. will obviously take time due to the nature of those operations and are advised against in a distributed environment.

Spark has data structures that do not support indexing, and hence `count()` will take almost a full search of the data.

Comment: I understand that! Is there something I can do

Comment: You cannot avoid the problem. @sanchaz

Comment: @sanchaz I understand where you come from.. but nothing we can do. You can try vectorized operations by enabling arrow but I haven't tried.

Comment: should I convert the csv file to libsvm format? if that's efficient